# Fsharp.Data, HtmlDocument has no extension Descendants

Tags: macos, visual-studio, f#, f#-data

I'm trying out f# on a mac and am running into a problem with a very simple script. I'm following [this tutorial](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/library/HtmlParser.html), however it breaks at results.Descendants ["a"].

Interestingly, VS recognises .Descendants as a valid method of results, but at runtime (trying just Descendants with no params) I get:

```
error CS1061: 'HtmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Descendants' and no 
extension method 'Descendants' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlDocument' could
be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It seems as if FSharp.Data is only partially imported or something. Interestingly, HtmlDocument works, but extensions don't.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: code

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org

open System
open FSharp.Data

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let results = HtmlDocument.Load("http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=FSharp.Data")
    let links = 
        results.Descendants "a"
        |> Seq.choose (fun x -> 
               x.TryGetAttribute("href")
               |> Option.map (fun a -> x.InnerText(), a.Value())
        )
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Edit2: I downloaded FSharp.Data with nuget manually and I can run the below script in fsharpi. I don't know what's the difference between this and whatever visual studio does?

```
#r "./FSharp.Data.2.4.6/lib/net45/FSharp.Data.dll" 
open FSharp.Data

let results = HtmlDocument.Load("http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=FSharp.Data")
let d= results.Descendants "a"
```

Edit 3: The differences between running in fsharpi and vs:

- fsharpi is using mono, while VS is using dotnet (which is .net core 2)
- nuget downloaded FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1, while VS is using 4.3.4

I can't seem to force VS to use FSharp.Core 4.0.0.1. Even if I add specific version, it still uses 4.3.4

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: Added the code in the post. FSharp.Data is added as NuGet dependency to the VS solution. The solution itself is a .Net core  Console App

Comment: do you use VSCode, right?

Comment: VS Community for mac: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/mac/

Comment: wow, that's amazing

Comment: what is your version of FSharp.Core?

Comment: 4.3.4. But it complains it needs .Net 4 something while the target is .Net core 2. This is the only possible issue I see.

Comment: Your exact code works fine for me in F# Interactive on Windows.  I suspect this might be an issue with the environment / runtime.

Comment: To make things more puzzling, it works in fsharpi for me as well ??

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem is in FCore.Sharp Visual Studio is using by default. To use specific version, it's not enough to add it through nuget, but one must add

```
<FSharpCoreImplicitPackageVersion>4.4.1.18</FSharpCoreImplicitPackageVersion>
```

to the project config. With that it seems the code works, but debugger (watch window) and immediate window **still** fail to recognise Descendants method. I don't know how that's even possible. I assume some kind of bug in VS.

Another option seems to be using FSharp.Data 3 beta (with the same watch/immediate problem)